# Changing the base SDK in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using Xcode 4.5. I developing an iOS app, I am targeting iOS 5.1.

I want to change the Base SDK to iOS 5.1, but it only displays iOS 6.

Where have all the others go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should always use the latest SDK. If you want to target older iOS versions, change the **Deployment Target** setting to the minimum iOS version you want to support.

Comment: Sure I'll do that. However I see autocomplete suggestions for classes and methods that are only available on iOS 6. That can lead to errors. That is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: That is a good thing though. You may want to optionally take advantage of newer capabilities on more recent iOS version. You just need to be careful of which APIs you use by checking the documentation and testing on real devices or the simulators.

Comment: Even if there are glaring flaws (e.g. crashes) in the latest SDK? Even when those crashes occur in methods available on all systems that are otherwise stable?

Comment: he asked for the base sdk and the accepted answer is changing the deployment target? Big difference between these two options...